# How to use Linq's lambda expression to query both aggregate and detail values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
var query = from i in listModel
group i by new { i.ClassId, i.Gender } into g
orderby g.Key.ClassId, g.Key.Gender
from item in g
select new
{
    g.Key.ClassId,
    g.Key.Gender,
    item.Name,
    Count = g.Count(),
    MaxAge = g.Max(i => i.Age),
    MinAge = g.Min(i => i.Age)
};
```

Using this code, I can find out the aggregated value (Count, MaxAge, MinAge) and the detailed value (Name) before grouping at the same time. How can the above statement be implemented by Linq's Lambda expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the conjunction of [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8), [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) and [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) extension methods

```cs
var query = listModel.GroupBy(i => new { i.ClassId, i.Gender })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.ClassId)
    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.Gender)
    .SelectMany(g => g, (g, item) => new
    {
        g.Key.ClassId,
        g.Key.Gender,
        item.Name,
        Count = g.Count(),
        MaxAge = g.Max(i => i.Age),
        MinAge = g.Min(i => i.Age)
    });
```